# Why is positional encoding needed while input ids already represent the order of words in Bert?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

For example, in Huggingface's example:

```
encoded_input = tokenizer("Do not meddle in the affairs of wizards, for they are subtle and quick to anger.")
print(encoded_input)
{'input_ids': [101, 2079, 2025, 19960, 10362, 1999, 1996, 3821, 1997, 16657, 1010, 2005, 2027, 2024, 11259, 1998, 4248, 2000, 4963, 1012, 102], 
 'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

The input_ids vector already encode the order of each token in the original sentence. Why does it need positional encoding again with an extra vector to represent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the design of the neural architecture. BERT consists of self-attention and feedforward sub-layers, and neither of them is sequential.

The feedforward layers process each token independently of others.

The self-attention views the input states as an unordered set of states. Attention can be interpreted as soft probabilistic retrieval from a set of values according to some keys. The position embeddings are there so the keys can contain information about their relative order.